# In Scala, where to put the code that should be executed in the primary constructor, to modify the arguments for instance?

Tags: scala, constructor

I am new to Scala and I come from a Java background.

I would like to know the Scala equivalent of this Java code:

```java
public class Person {
    
    String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

So, when creating Person object, we directly put the lower case version

Comment: You can just do the same thing similar to Java: `class Person(_name: String) { val name: String = _name.toLowerCase() }` The whole class body is constructor.

Comment: So in this case, Person class will have 2 fields, _name and name?

Comment: if you don't declare  `_name` as val and doesn't use it in a method, it will not be a field but only a constructor parameter. Otherwise if you declare it as a val, or use it in a method to be used later on, Scala will make it a `private[this] val` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is roughly what you want:

```
class Person private(val name: String)

object Person {
  def apply(name: String): Person =
    new Person(name.toLowerCase)
}

val p = Person("Tim") // == Person.apply("Tim")

p.name // tim
```

The `private` modifier means that you cannot create the class directly using `new`.

The `object` has the same name as the class and is the *companion object* for the class. It has full access to the class, including being able to construct instances using `new`.

The `apply` method is used when you "call" an object, and this modifies the parameters before calling the actual constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it mandatory to make a companion object, or apply can be in the Person class? Also, if the constructor has many parameters, and we would only want to modify one, do we have to declare them all in apply?

Comment: @Ana you may also declare a secondary constructor or you can have a private variable that you only modify in the constructor body. However the most common and idiomatic solution is the `apply` in the companion, or using a **refined type** for the lower cased string.

Comment: Why does name need to be a val? apply is called before assigning, if I understand correctly.

Comment: If `name` is not `val` it will not be visible from outside the class. Only `val` parameters of the constructor appear as fields of the class. With a `case class` the parameters are all fields, so `val` is not required.